# I can't figure out how to use visibilityFilters in react redux todo app

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a todo app that does all 4 crud operations but I can't filter them based on their current status [here's the app on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/problems-with-redux-zfgnw?file=/src/redux/reducers/visibilityFilter.js).

```
import { SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER } from "../actionTypes";

const initialState = {
  filters: ["SHOW_ALL"]
};

const visibilityFilter = (state = initialState, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER:
      return { payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default visibilityFilter;
```

Any explanations will be appreciated.

I have also checked other react redux todo app github repos but most of them are old and it didn't look like they were writing in the best possible way, so I am trying to find a better way (and so far failing at it)

Comment: What does the `visibilityFilter` reducer have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues

1. `filters` is an array in the initial state, but you send single values there after in your action, and you also use it a single value when filtering with it.
2. you expect `payload` in your reducer but the data you dispatch does not wrap things in `payload`

   ```
   dispatch({
      type: SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER,
      filter
    });
   ```
3. in continuation to the above you should use the already defined action `setFilter` for setting a filter, which correctly wrap the data in a `payload` property.

fixing these 3 issues, you get https://codesandbox.io/s/problems-with-redux-forked-hv36h which is working as intended.

Comment: There is a `switch` case inside Todolist component where the redux state is mutated. This should also be fixed.

Comment: this solves the issues, thanks a lot, but what is the correct way to dispatching set filter action* without mutating the redux store and keeping both reducers separate?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is an anti-pattern when you mutate the redux state variable inside the component like this:

```
const getVisibleTodos = (todos, filter) => {
    switch (filter) {
      case "SHOW_ALL":
        return todos;
      case "SHOW_COMPLETED":
        return todos.filter((t) => t.completed);
      case "SHOW_ACTIVE":
        return todos.filter((t) => !t.completed);
      default:
        return todos;
    }
  };
```

Instead what you should do, listen to the `SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER` action on `toDoReducer.js`:

```
 //import SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER action

 case SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER:
     let toDoClone = [...state.todos]
     //if(filter = something)
     toDoClone.filter(t => //your condition)
     return {
       ...state,
       todos: toDoClone
     }
```